# Recommendation for software development workflow apps

Tags: software-testing

I am trying to create a traceable workflow path from requirement gathering to development and finally to testing. The objective is to ensure that for each section or module in requirement spec a specific tested code based is identified for component based programming.

The company currently maintains requirement specs in word document. I came across  ReqIT based ProR plugin for eclipse for this. The idea is to ensure reusability of requirements. Now from ReqIT I want to move the modularised requirements to a test case which is built modularly around a standard test plan document.

Finally I need a way to link the requirements, test report to give a good feedback loop for developers too.

The query is what software systems do you all use that can integrate well end to end. I would prefer it being opensource if possible but if the experience and resulting effiency is better paid systems like Jira I am open to exploring, having low adoption time also a priority.

I zeroed in on test collab & mantis so far. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020869/seeking-a-true-tool-chain is somewhat related